# String safe way to cut a string (Windows kernel)

Tags: c++, string, kernel

I'm writing a small minifilter, and I need to take the last 3 characters from a UNICODE_STRING, in order to test if the file extension is "txt".

At the moment, my solution is to manually modify the UNICODE_STRING manually:

```
UNICODE_STRING fileName = fileNameInfos->Name; // get file name 
USHORT charsToRemove = fileName.Length / 2 - 3;
fileName.Length -= sizeof(WCHAR) * charsToRemove;
fileName.MaximumLength -= sizeof(WCHAR) * charsToRemove;
fileName.Buffer = fileName.Buffer + charsToRemove;
```

and then to create a new UNICODE_STRING containing "txt" to compare it:

```
RtlCreateUnicodeString(&compareString,L"txt");
if(RtlEqualUnicodeString(&compareString, &fileName))
{ // do stuff }
```

but I don't think that manually modifying the buffer and the parameters of the UNICODE_STRING is the right way. Does anyone have a string safe solution to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with UNICODE_STRING?  You mean some kind of encoding?  Is it encoded as utf-8, utf-16 or utf-32 ???

Comment: This is the structure definition from the MSDN website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I hope that that's enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually for my needs FltParseFileNameInformation was enough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I hope that someone can find it useful